# try/catch not working for static member throwable class?

Tags: java

I am having some issues with throwing static member classes, as the title suggests. But I'm not sure if that's the problem, and the compiler gives me mixed signals as to what I should be doing! My program's classes and functions are all in a single file.

Here's the definition of one of my Throwables (the others are essentially the same):

```
private static class ParenthesisException extends Throwable
{
    public ParenthesisException(){}
    public String strErrMsg()
    {
        return "ERROR: Every '(' needs a matching ')'";
    }
}
```

I'm throwing this in a member function that gets called by `main` inside a try/catch, statement. I throw my other `Throwable` class inside a function being called by said function being called by `main` in the try/catch statement. Here's a little segment of it:

```
try
{
    parseFormula(cin.nextLine());
}
catch(ParenthesisException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.strErrMsg());
}
catch(OperatorException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.strErrMsg());
}
```

parseFormula is the static member function throwing `ParenthesisException`.

The compiler says:

> Unreachable catch block for jcalc.ParenthesisException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

but I *did* throw it, here, in parseFormula:

```
if(n_lpar != n_rpar)
    throw new ParenthesisException();
```

Oddly enough, when I remove the try/catch, it tells me that the exception isn't caught. This confuses me, because before, it said that `ParenthesisException` was never thrown, and now it says it is never caught, but *is* thrown.

I'm wondering if this is related to the way they are all static members(the classes and functions), and how I can resolve this.

Comment: please format your code! it is a pain to read otherwise.

Comment: @Wolfcow: done @ OP what is parseFormula's method signature?

Comment: @Wolfcow: Can you explain to me how to format my code? @cularis: `private static double parseFormula(String formula)`

Comment: for the future @Uronym, after your copy and paste your code into stackoverflow and highlight it as code, you can go and add return lines and space it out so it looks better. it just helps make the code more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not declaring that `parseFormula()` throws an exception.

When you declare `parseFormula()` you need to add `throws ParenthesisException`.

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem. I changed the signature to `private static parseFormula(String formula) throws OperatorException, ParenthesisException`

Comment: The compiler complains when an exception is thrown inside a function being called by the function inside a try/catch statement. If I have a nested function like that, would I need to include what's being thrown in nested functions in the signature of the top-level function _and_ the nested functions?

Comment: Any function that potentially can throw an exception and does not handle it itself needs to declare that it throws (whatever)Exception.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is that your `ParenthesisException` extends Throwable directly.

You should not do this. Extend Excption if you wish your exception to be checked exception (that compiler forces you to catch it), RuntimeException if you do not want compiler to force you or Error if you think that this is something fatal.

Answer (score 0):

```
try { 
    parseFormula(cin.nextLine()); //This doesn't actually throw anything
} catch(ParenthesisException e) { 
    System.out.println(e.strErrMsg()); 
} catch(OperatorException e) { 
    System.out.println(e.strErrMsg()); 
}
```

`parseFormula` needs to be declared with `throws ParenthesisException, OperatorException` so that when you call it in the try it knows that the method can throw exceptions, otherwise you are trying to do something it thinks doesn't throw any exceptions and therefore complains saying that you are never throwing any exceptions in the try block and because of that there is nothing to catch.

EDIT: [I must be a slow typer, didn't see the two new answers but yes I agree with what J Lundberg said]